# html input tag always reads null in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to try a simple login page. I add a few text fields and want to read them using javascript or jquery. The issue I'm having is that I'm getting a null error every time using javascript and a blank using jquery, even if I type text into the field.

html:

```
<label id='userNameLabel' class='inputLabel' for='userNameInput'>Username</label>
<input id='userNameInput' name='User' class='userInput' type='text' value=''>
<label id='passwordLabel' class='inputLabel' for='passwordInput'>Password</label>
<input id='passwordInput' name='Password' class='userInput' type='text' value=''>
<input id='submitSignIn' class='button' type='submit' value='Log In'>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#submitSignIn').click(function(){
  $userName = $('#userNameInput').text();
  $userName = $('#passwordInput').text();
  $rememberMe = $('#rememberMe').val();
 });
})
```

-or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#submitSignIn').click(function(){
  $userName = document.getElementById(userNameInput).value;
  $userName = document.getElementById(passwordInput).value;
  $rememberMe = document.getElementById(rememberMe).value;
 });
})
```

Can anyone tell me why I'm having this issue?

Comment: the jquery function to get an input value is `.val()`, not `.text()`

Comment: instead of using .click() you should probably use .submit() on the form

Comment: to elaborate more on my previous comment: People can submit form even without really clicking; Or you may want to submit the form programatically later, what do you know... That's why .click() on the submit button is less reliable than $("form").submit(funtion(){});

Comment: @Lukas1 but it will work. OP: did you check your console? Does it give any errors? And in the JS `#rememberMe` is undefined. Check my fiddle for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/GuyT/9evt6s6b/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$userName = $('#userNameInput').text();
```

This attempts to take the *child nodes* of the input and extract the text from them.

Input elements can't have any child nodes. You want `val()`.

```
$userName = document.getElementById(userNameInput).value;
```

This attempts to get the element by the id in the string variable `userNameInput`, which is undeclared. You need to put quotes around it to make it a string literal.

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery is using `.text()` rather than `.val()` - inputs are self-closing elements, hence do not have any text.

Your JavaScript is missing quote marks around `userNameInput`, meaning it is getting the variable `userNameInput` rather than the string `"userNameInput"`.

Answer (score -1):

for check bus use is checked method

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#submitSignIn').click(function(){
      $userName = $('#userNameInput').val();
      $userPass = $('#passwordInput').val();
     })
```

;